# How to externally access a kubernetes service of type as "NodePort", using ec2 Public IP

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, iptables, kubernetes

On ec2, running a single node k8s cluster. On the node, a service is running with the type as "NodePort" with the exposed port "31380".

I need to access this service externally over port 80.

```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: demo-nginx
    labels:
      run: demo-nginx
  spec:
    ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
    selector:
      run: demo-nginx
    type: **NodePort**
```

What additional config is needed to access this from ec2 public IP e.g. a successful "curl ec2publicIp:80" or via a browser?

```
> ~$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
demo-nginx   NodePort    10.107.6.8   <none>        80:31380/TCP   17m
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP        23m
```

Note#1) I'm able to access the service from inside the Node, using the privateIP.

> curl 172.31.8.98:31380

Note#2) 
I have tried a combination of IPtable rules e.g.-

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.31.8.98:31380
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Note#3) My ec2 security group and rule is configured to allow http traffic.

Note#4) I have updated the IP forwarding on my EC2 instance.

Note#5) The k8s service exposes a simple nginx deployment.

```
> $ kubectl get deployments
NAME         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
demo-nginx   1/1     1            1           43m
```

Any insight to this issue would be highly be highly appreciated.

N.B. I already searched many contents but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the solution to expose Kubernetes service externally (outside the cluster) then Kubernetes [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress) resource would be the best choice to achieve this goal. `Ingress`, specifically used to offer functionality for HTTP and HTTPS routing from outside the cluster to the nested Kubernetes services.

When you have considered to use `Ingress`, first step before `ingress controller` installation would be selection of the appropriate ingress provider, which should satisfy specific cloud platform requirements.

For AWS, I would bet for using `NGINX Ingress Controller` as it naively offers L4 or L7 level for [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/), you can find more information about `ingress-nginx` implementation [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws).

In case you've used [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) to build your cluster, take a look at the `ingress-nginx` installation [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/master/addons/ingress-nginx).

I would also recommend to check [AWS ALB Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller) for Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `kubectl port-forward`.

Try this command out in a separate terminal: `kubectl port-forward pod/demo-nginx 9998:80` and then try to do a `curl localhost:80`. If you want to run this in the background, just put a `&` at the end of the command.

Please note that this is only going to work on your computer. If you want to expose this to the world I would advise you look into using a LoadBalancer type service or some sort of Ingress resource.